# Why is this iframe not loading?

Tags: html, iframe

Why won't this iframe work? I can't see why it isn't.

```
<iframe src='https://www.etsy.com/listing/175183631/beautiful-heroic-knights-armour'>
You browser does not support iframes and so cannot utilise our store.
</iframe>
```

Comment: take a look into X-Frame-Options.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x-frame-options

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript